# How to get url if directory or file exist?

Tags: php, mod-rewrite, httpd.conf

I need to get url if directory or file exist.
my config:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -d
RewriteRule .* ./user.php?action=$0  [QSA]
```

my php file:

```
  <?php
  if (isset($_GET['action'])) {
  echo $_GET['action'];
  }
  ?>
```

Answer (score 0):

Please try with following code :-

```
$path = 'path/to/file_or_dir';
if ( file_exists( $path )){

    $url  = (@$_SERVER["HTTPS"] == "on") ? "https://" : "http://";
    $url .=$_SERVER["SERVER_NAME"]. dirname( $path ); 
    echo $url; 

}
```